# git checkout takes hours

Tags: git, git-lfs

I am experimenting with my selfhosted GitLab instance, so I pushed my git repo to it. The repository on GitLab consumes 14 GB and includes several lfs objects. Cloning my branch with the command below takes around 1-2 minutes.

```
$ git clone http://[ip:port]/repo/bavoo.git
Cloning into 'bavoo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 773299, done.
remote: Total 773299 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 773299
Receiving objects: 100% (773299/773299), 541.07 MiB | 2.44 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (633879/633879), done.
```

But the following checkout takes longer than two hours (maybe even longer, I cancelled it). I don't know what git is doing. Is there any chance to see what takes so long to checkout a branch?

```
$ git checkout bavoo_test
```

For completeness, here are the version numbers of my OS, `git` and `git lfs`

```
$ macos-version
10.15.3 (19D76)
$ git --version
git version 2.24.1
$ git lfs --version
git-lfs/2.8.0 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.12.7)
```

**Edit:**

As requested, here is the output of `git lfs env`:

```
Endpoint=http://[ip:port]/repo/bavoo.git/info/lfs (auth=basic)
LocalWorkingDir=/Users/daniel/Desktop/bavoo
LocalGitDir=/Users/daniel/Desktop/bavoo/.git
LocalGitStorageDir=/Users/daniel/Desktop/bavoo/.git
LocalMediaDir=/Users/daniel/Desktop/bavoo/.git/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=/Users/daniel/Desktop/bavoo/.git/lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=3
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=/Users/daniel/Desktop/bavoo/.git/lfs
AccessDownload=basic
AccessUpload=basic
DownloadTransfers=basic
UploadTransfers=basic
GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.24.1/libexec/git-core
```

Comment: What does `git lfs env` say? Also try setting the `GIT_TRACE` environment variable to `1`. My guess is its either downloading 14 GB which will take about 1-2 hours at 2.4 MB/s, or it's quietly waiting for you to enter authentication.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer. I will definitely try `GIT_TRACE` in the meantime

Comment: Thank you soo much!!! I would accept your comment as an answer! I just found out that my hostname does not match my IP. My hostname of my gitlab installation was different during installation

Comment: Glad to help! Odd that `git-lfs` did not timeout.

Comment: Actually the company firewall to that address took a minute to respond and denied the access, so it kept trying and trying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `git lfs env` and make sure everything looks ok.

Set the `GIT_TRACE` environment variable to `1` to get debugging information.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `git checkout` involves LFS remote interaction under the hood.

If you just need checkout locally, you have these options;

- `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 git checkout origin/master` -- to checkout without download from remote
- `git reset --soft origin/master` to go to the commit hash without changing your workspace

Needless to say, `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE` can be exported so that you don't have to type it always when git checkout. Or you can work with `.lfsconfig` to disable automatic LFS download, see this https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2717.